# Move top div with scroll jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a question: how could move the top of a div as I move the scroll down?

It is like putting on position: fixed, but do not want to do that and for that reason wonder what else can?

Thanks for the help

Comment: maybe, but i can't use fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/vb0o2s3s/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("section div").each(function(){
    $(this).css('margin-top',$(window).scrollTop()-$(this).parent().position().top);
    });
});
```